# extjs 6 grid scrollbar jumping

Tags: extjs, scroll, grid, scrollbar, extjs6

I have an extjs 6.0.1.250 grid, with a remote json store, it is loading every 2 seconds, to refresh its data. It shows a device list with the device statuses, about 200 lines. (name, uptime, etc...)

When a user scrolls the scrollbar with the mouse the grid does not keep its position but jumps with to the old place. Is there a solution to use it normally with scrolling?

Using a taskManager:

```
this.config.pmConfig.deviceRefreshTask =
            {

            run: function()
            {
                var store=this.getDevicesGetDevicesStore();

                store.proxy.setExtraParam('eventDisableLoader', true);
                store.load();

            },
            interval: 2000, // 2 second, this will update the progressbar
            scope: this
        };

        Ext.TaskManager.start(this.config.pmConfig.deviceRefreshTask); // start the first timer
```

And here is the grid:

```
xtype: 'gridpanel',
viewConfig: {
    loadMask: false
},
itemId: 'devicesGrid',
width: 40,
title: '``Devices``',
emptyText: '``There is no device in this group.``',
store: 'Devices.GetDevices',
columns: [
    {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        hidden: true,
        width: 80,
        align: 'right',
        dataIndex: 'id',
        text: 'Id'
    },
//....... more normal and some action columns.....
],
viewConfig: {
    itemId: 'devicesGridTableView',
    loadMask: false,
    preserveScrollOnRefresh: true,
    preserveScrollOnReload: true,
    plugins: [
        {
            ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
            ddGroup: 'deviceGroups',
            enableDrop: false
        }
    ]
},
tabConfig: {
    xtype: 'tab',
    dock: 'left'
},
features: [
    {
        ftype: 'grouping',
        groupHeaderTpl: [
            '<b>{name}</b>'
        ]
    }
],
selModel: {
    selType: 'checkboxmodel'
}
```

Comment: Does the same happen if you call `setExtraParam` only once (not in the timer), load the store initially once with `load()` (or set `autoLoad: true` on the store), and in the timer you call `reload()` instead of `load()`?

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, but id does not helped. :( I removed the setExtra param, and changed to reload, but it is the same.
It is about 200 lines data, so it is not much. :(

Any other idea?

Comment: I guess it's classic toolkit, or not?

Comment: In the grid definition you can try to use `bufferedRenderer: false,`

Comment: @Arthur  Thank you, it seems to me the bufferedRenderer: false is helped. I'll test it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arthurs suggestion is helped: "In the grid definition you can try to use bufferedRenderer: false"

thanks.